# Shortcuts to surround text by curly braces, and more

Tags: osx, text-processing, keyboard-shortcuts

Many times I need to simply surround some text by some signs, like curly braces, square brackets and more depending on what it is exactly I am writing, scripting or programming.

Some programs, like TexPad and a few others, have options to set up these commands, but I'd like to have these options working outside of this program also.

Even when writing at various online site, like *StackExchange*, the syntax, which I think is great, I need to surround text by `*`, and other signs for the markup. Then it would be great to be able to just select some text, and press a key combination, and the text would be surrounded by the chosen signs.

This could possibly also work, if there was a small non-obtrusive GUI, like for instance *Popclip*, which does have this feature, but I don't really like it too much. Sometimes it doesn't show up, or acts slow. Also no keyboard shortcuts.

[image: Popclip shortcutkey]

I've tried searching a bit, but didn't really find any programs that does this globally. Also, it needs to work on Mac OSX El Capitan (and beyond)

Comment: Must it work with any program? Would a Firefox add-on be OK, for instance?

Comment: Yes, it needs to work with all programs where one would write.

Answer (score 1):

If your ok with doing a light-amount of scripting, I think you'd find [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) can perform some of the features you desire. If your into scripting, you'll find AHK's language to be somewhat reasonable. I've had moderate success with this application myself.

My regret is that it does not have mac or linux support. I'm afraid the uni-platform hotkey scene is somewhat lacking.

Comment: I've actually been using ControllerMate to reassign many keys with applescripts running. But it is unable to sync settings to different devices, and it is not a very elegant scripting-language, as it is graphical scripting.